# Find an orthonormal basis for a subspace, which is given by a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the real vector space of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ an inner product on $V$ given by $$\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)x^2 \, dx$$

Let $W$ be the subspace of $V$ spanned by  $f_1(x) = 1$ and $f_2(x) = x^3$. Find an orthonormal basis for $W$.

I used the Gram-Schmidt process, and I got the orthonormal basis $f_a(x) = 1$ and $f_b(x) = x^3 - \frac{1}{2}$ but I am not sure they are normal or not.. Please help me to figure it out! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\langle f_a,f_b\rangle
&= \int_0^1 f_a(x)f_b(x) x^2 \, dx
= \int_0^1 1\cdot(x^3-\tfrac12) x^2 \, dx
\\&= \int_0^1 x^5-\tfrac12x^2 \, dx
\\&= \frac16\left[x^6-x^3\right]_0^1 = 0,
\end{align}$$
so they are orthogonal, but not (yet) orthonormal
since $\langle f_a,f_a \rangle \ne 1 \ne \langle f_b,f_b \rangle$:
$$\langle f_a,f_a\rangle \int_0^1 x^2 \, dx = \frac13  \left[x^3\right]_0^1=\frac13$$
$$\langle f_b,f_b\rangle \int_0^1 (x^3-\tfrac12)^2x^2 \, dx = \frac19 \left[ (x^3-\tfrac12)^3 \right]_0^1=\frac1{36}$$
So $\{\sqrt3f_a,6f_b\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $W$.